# Getting System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. while trying to upload a file from Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, file-upload, angular-material, azure-blob-storage

"System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format while trying to upload a file" from my Angular application to asp.net 6 backend api. My client side code goes as follows

```
 onFileSelected(event: any) {

    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);    
    debugger;
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
  
    // const formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append('file', file);
  
    this.http.post(this.BaseUrl + '/api/FileUpload/upload', formData).subscribe(response => {
      console.log('File uploaded successfully');
    });
  }
```

and server side code as

```
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        // Retrieve the connection string from configuration
        var connectionString = _storageConnectionString;

        // Create a BlobServiceClient object
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

        // Get a reference to the container where you want to upload the file
        var containerName = "mycontainer";
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Create a unique name for the blob
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        // Upload the file to Azure Storage
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), true);

        // Return a response to the client
        return Ok();
    }
```

I am not able to get any solution for the issue.

Turns out the code never reaches the back end as I never get a debugger hit in the back end, whereas while trying to test the method from swagger, it works fine.

Comment: Could you pls try code like this   `public async Task<IActionResult> Upload() { var file = Request.Form.Files[0];` or like this `public async Task<IActionResult> Upload() { var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync(); var file = formCollection.Files[0];`

Comment: Tried, but still getting the exception "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.\r\n   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)\r\n   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)\r\n

Answer (score 1):

For testing purpose, I created an Angular project with .net core web api. Here is the code of web page:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>
<div class="file-upload">
    {{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary"class="upload-btn"       
      (click)="fileUpload.click()">
        click
    </button>
</div>
```

and here is the code for uploading files action:

```
fileName = '';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 onFileSelected(event) { 
    const file:File = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        this.fileName = file.name; 
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("thumbnail", file);
        const upload$ = this.http.post("https://localhost:7212/home/upload", formData);
        upload$.subscribe();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code from api side:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()//IFormFile file
{   
    var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
    return Ok();
}
```

At last is my test result:
[image]

You can see from the screenshot, the file has been uploaded successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I never managed to get the IFormFile to work, I guess that should be past of a class that is used.

My first [Google result](https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/) looks like code that I used in the past. This is verified to work.

The part you need to change is the way you read the file in dotnet core.

```cs
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
    try
    {
        var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
   
        var file = formCollection.Files.First();
```

Comment: Why IFormFile file can't work ? The backend api can work in swagger, why you suggest to change the api code ?